# How to use List to display objects of a Model Map in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, list

I apologize in advance for an ambiguity or poor terminology that I use. I'm attempting to use List in order to convert the objects of a Model Map and then display the output in a corresponding jsp, but I'm having trouble understanding what I'm doing wrong. "Collections.List" returns an error "cannot find symbol" although I've imported java.util.List, which I thought could be called from Collections.

I appreciate any assistance and I'm willing to provide any clarification necessary.

```
@RequestMapping(
value  = "/updateProducts.htm",
method = RequestMethod.GET
)
public String list(ModelMap modelMap) {

    List<Product> products;
        products = Collections.List(modelMap.values());

modelMap.addAttribute("updateProductsForm", new UpdateProductsForm());
modelMap.addAttribute("products", products);

public String list(ModelMap modelMap) {
```

I followed your advice. But now I'm getting errors on "elements" in "products.elements", as well as "modelMap.values" still. I added java.util.Collections as well as java.util.Enumeration ..

```
List<Product> products;
    products = Collections.list(modelMap.values());

for (Enumeration<Product> e = products.elements(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
            System.out.println(e.nextElement());
        }

modelMap.addAttribute("updateProductsForm", new UpdateProductsForm());
modelMap.addAttribute("products", products);
```

Comment: There is no Collections.List (capital 'L'), there is Collections.list() but that takes an Enumeration: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#list(java.util.Enumeration). Also, you need to import java.util.Collections and not just java.util.List.

Comment: create your own function to convert the Modelmap values to list..

Comment: Updated code included in the edit above.. still getting errors on "modelmap.values" and "elements" in "product.elements" ...

Answer (score 0):

ModelMap.values() return a Collection object, to convert the collection to List either use iterator and add the elements of the collection to list or else use code as below.

```
ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>(modelMap.values());
```

Now that we got list of products which can be added to modelAndView and can be used to iterate on a jsp.